# How to assign values to an array except certain elements in fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to assign values to an array with a certain rule, except the 5th element due to divide-by-zero problem. The program is like follows:

```
    program main
        implicit none
      real(8) :: a(10)
      integer :: i

      a(5) = 0d0
      do i = 1, 10
         if (i /= 5) then
            a(i) = 1.0d0 / dble(i-5)
         end if
         write(*,*) a(i)
      end do

      stop
    end program main
```

Is there a more smart/efficient way to do the same thing?
Thank you very much!

Comment: So that we can judge our solutions, what do you consider to be not-smart or inefficient with what you currently have?

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear. The "smart/efficient" way I mean is to avoid the "if" in the loop, or even no loop, without causing errors. I guess it is not necessary to use "if" in the loop, since only one exception value is required to deal with. But I don't know how to. Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: If I use two loops "do i = 1,4" and "do i=6,10", could it be faster than my original code? More generally, if there is "izero" that makes a(i)==0 in "i=1,n", can I use "do i=1,izero-1" and "do i=izero+1,n"? Will there be errors if "do i=1,0" or "do i=n+1,n"?

Comment: `do I=1,0` is not an error, and is a loop with zero iterations.

Comment: Do you really encounter an issue with this piece of code? Is it unclear? slow? What exactly are you expecting? Of course you may find a tricky (and even elegant) way of achieving what you are asking, but it may be a bad idea to focus on such micro-optimization points: you will win close to nothing  and probably end with a more difficult to understand code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the amount of source code:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dbl = kind(1.d0)
  real(dbl) :: a(10)
  integer :: i

  do i = 1, 10
    a(i) = 1._dbl / (i-5)
  end do
  a(5) = 0

  ! I expect you want to do something more than just this with the array
  do i = 1, 10
    write(*,*) a(i)
  end do
end program
```

As francescalus points out this may cause your program to crash if floating point exceptions are enabled. Anyway, also notice other things I used, which can shorten your code. `= 0` instead of `= 0.d0`, avoiding the `dbl()` (use `real(x,dbl)` instead if necessary) and so on.

If this code is repeated very often, you could also save some CPU time by avoiding the branch. In a typical initialization code it is irrelevant.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this may, or may not, signal divide-by-zero.

Comment: Absolutely true. Perhaps I am too used to this. I never enable FP exceptions in my production code. They slow everything down considerably.

Comment: It works! Thank you and francescalus for both the solution and notes!